# DataSource getConnection() configuring connection timeout with jndi

Tags: java, database-connection, jndi

I'm having a problem configuring the timeout that is used when establishing a new connection to an Oracle database when using a connection pool.

I'm using `DBCP` in Tomcat and XML to configure the resource .

In the source code I get a `DataSource` and connection like this:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/anncDB");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

This works fine if the IP specified in the url is available. But if it is not available, it takes 3 minutes before `getConnection()` returns. I need to configure this to be smaller.

I've tried `setLoginTimeout()`, but that doesn't work. Doing `ds.setLoginTimeout()` takes 3 minutes before failing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You said that you use XML for declaring the resource.
So i suppose you have something like that :

```
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="javauser" password="javadude" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>
```

In this case, watch the maxWait attribute.
In the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html), it's specified that it's the hmaximum time to wait for a database connection to become available (10s in the example).

Hope this help

Comment: here is my XML :                                                                                                     
<Resource name="jdbc/anncDB"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
maxActive="10"
maxIdle="1"
maxWait="5000"
username="xxxx"
password="xxxx"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
url="jdbcracle:thin:@10.0.0.0:1521:ODS"
factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"/>
</Context>

Comment: may be you could test ds.setMaxWait(aDurationInMilliseconds)